# Create list Item and add versioning using Powershell

Tags: powershell, versioning

I have export list item data inducing version in CSV file

[image]

in above picture item ID 1 has version 1, 2 and 3.

I have enable version in list.

so I'm trying to create list item with first version and trying to update remaining version on that list item

Please help me with this.